# Exporting pictures from iOS device without using a computer

Tags: ios, graphics, sd-card

How can export pictures on an iOS device to an SD card or a USB memory stick without using a computer?

Answer (score 1):

Since the iPhone and iPod Touch don't have an SD card port or the inherent ability to mount a USB memory stick, you'll need to purchase 3rd party hardware (and potentially software) to transfer data to either of these media types *without a computer*.

A [Google search on the subject](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=iphone%20sd%20card%20reader&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) could help. I can't make a product recommendation, but one place to start is with some reviews like this one at [Wired's Gadget Lab](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/02/zoomit-an-sd-card-reader-for-iphone/)

Comment: It's worth noting that the Camera Connection Kit is meant to import data *from* an SD card *onto* an iPad, not the other way around. As far as I know, it can't be used to offload pictures from the iPad. Or can it?

Comment: @DanJ, no, it can't.  I've correct that error in the answer with an edit.

Comment: @DanJ I haven't tried it myself, but I remember seeing a JailBreak package that enabled writing to the Camera Connection Kit *and* enabled reading (and writing) on more devices. I'm not sure what it's called, but I believe it's out there somewhere.